# HTML Snapshot for google using ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, seo

I have a website which content is created dynamically on the client using ajax, and I want to create a HTML snapshot for google crawler.
Since I Use ASP.net, my idea is to create an instance of WebBrowser control on the server, whenever google passes '_escaped_fragment_' parameter, then load my dynamic page on the server, and then return google the created page.
I have two questions:
1. Is there a better way to do this?
2. If there is no better way to do this, how should I implement it? should I use http handlers?

Comment: What is your goal?  Are you trying to create rich snippets that may (indirectly) improve your SEO?  Also, in IIS7, you can go to http response headers, and then for sure set common headers to 30 or 45 .... this is good for SEO.

Comment: @Andy: This might be of help: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

This may be late. Have you tried NHTMLUNIT(which is a wrapper to HTMLUNIT)?